# Extended Fragment Stil Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to use the method

```
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new MappingPage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

I have written a class called MappingPage(), if I try to use the above method, the fragment I create is of type MappingPage because has been extended and hence throw an error as the function returns a fragment (not a MappingPage Object)

EDIT:I am getting an error when I do

```
  Fragment fragment = new MappingPage();
```

Eclipse tell me that I need to change fragment to type MappingPage, which means i have to change the return type of the function

two Questions 
1) How are you supposed to put your custom fragments into this?

2) Why does the dummySectionFrament return a Fragment Object and not a DummySectionFragment object?

thanks in advance

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

here is my class

```
public class MappingPage  extends Fragment
{
 private MapView map;
 private MapController myMapController;
 public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "1";

 public MappingPage() {
 }

public  View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.fragment_theme);
    //LayoutInflater Inflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    map = (MapView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myMapController = map.getController();
    myMapController.setZoom(15);
    super.onResume();
}




}
```

Comment: This should work. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: It's not unlikely you mixed up the `Fragment` imports. Fragments live both in the SDK as well as in the support library, and you can't mix them. It's quite a common mistake to make. You'll want to use the support flavour for `ViewPager`, so make sure the imports point to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and *not* `android.app.Fragment`.

Comment: MH I have changed the import on MappingPage and it works perfect, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, this should work. `MappingPage` is an indirect instance of the `Fragment` class, and you can therefore return it.

About question two, the method that you call always returns a specific type, like `Fragment` in the case of `getItem()`. However, this can be a subclass of that as well, and if you are sure it is, you can safely cast it to that subclass.